# Cakephp and MySQL with huge data

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cakephp

I am working on Call reports module, where all the data automatically enters in to through Calling Agent's progress (through web-services). Data usually exceeds from 3000 records to 15000 records per day. So, all my queries for data rendering works fine. But when data becomes large (millions of records), each query takes more than 3 to 4 minutes and some time memory get exhausted.

*This is my Table cdr Schema, which is [MyISAM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/myisam-storage-engine.html) based and auto-increment id:*

```
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `p_gateway` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `callerid` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `dialedtime` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `start` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `end` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `t_name` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `destnumber` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `deviceip` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `p_gateway` (`p_gateway`)
ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=159 ;
```

*And some data:*

```
id  |user_id | p_gateway    | callerid | dialedtime | date         | start | end | t_name      |  destnumber       | deviceip        |  status
158 | 4      | '100'        | '100'    | 0          | '2016-05-07' | '0'   | '0' | ''          | '900234598610121' | ''              | ''
157 | 4      | '100'        | '100'    | 0          | '2016-05-07' | '0'   | '0' | ''          | '00223459610121'  | ''              | ''
155 | 3      | '1001'       | '1001'   | 0          | '2016-05-06' | '0'   | '0' | 'interncal' | '2342344925027'   | '133.168.0.175' | 'CANCEL'
156 | 3      | '1001'       | '1001'   | 0          | '2016-05-06' | '0'   | '0' | 'interncal' | '988558855925027' | '166.168.0.175' | 'CHANUNAVAIL');
```

*This is my Cdr table's Model:*

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
class Cdr extends AppModel {

  public $useTable = 'cdr';
  public $belongsTo = array(
        'User' => array(
            'className' => 'User',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id'
        )
    );

}
?>
```

*My Controller side Query:*

```
$this->Cdr->recursive = -1;    
$this->Paginator->settings = array(
  'conditions' => array(
    'Cdr.user_id' => 2,
    'Cdr.date >=' => '2016-04-1',
    'Cdr.date <=' => '2016-04-30'
  ),
  'limit' => 100,
  'order'=> "Cdr.id DESC",
  'contain' => array(
      'User' => array(
        'fields' => array(
          'User.username'
        )
      )
  )
);
```

*And Query Output:*

```
SELECT `Cdr`.`id`, `Cdr`.`user_id`, `Cdr`.`p_gateway`, 
       `Cdr`.`callerid`, `Cdr`.`dialedtime`, `Cdr`.`date`, 
       `Cdr`.`start`, `Cdr`.`end`, `Cdr`.`t_name`, `Cdr`.`destnumber`,
       `Cdr`.`deviceip`, `Cdr`.`status`, `User`.`username`
   FROM `vpn1`.`cdr_archives` AS `Cdr` 
   LEFT JOIN `vpn1`.`users` AS `User` ON (`Cdr`.`user_id` = `User`.`id`) 
   WHERE `Cdr`.`user_id` = 2 AND `Cdr`.`date` >= '2016-04-1'
          AND `Cdr`.`date` <= '2016-04-30'
   ORDER BY `Cdr`.`id` DESC LIMIT 100
```

In few scenarios, I needs to query through varchar field and some time I need to query by date or time. Query takes lot of time on the other hand I'm using JQuery Ajax for fetching data.

I have also used, `[$this->Model->recursive = -1;][2]` and also added the specific fields to query.

I by doing `[Configure::write('debug', 0);][2]`, it doesn't effect that much with big data.

**So, what approach should I use? Indexing in my table or something other approach?**

> I'm using in Cakephp 2.6.1.

Comment: You ask for indexing, why haven't you tried adding indexes to the foreign keys when you already ask for it? So go, try it (user_id).

Comment: Yes index the joining columns

Comment: I tried it, but didn't get much luck!

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select-optimization.html try this

Comment: In addition, if indexing is not helped for you, you can try do Join on php side, not on database side - In array. For example Select users in array and after that show it by `$key[$value];`